# Vertical select input in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am interested in making the select input that controls the variable on the y-axis of a graph vertical, ie. parallel to the axis itself. I have looked around SO and Posit but have found nothing that indicates this is possible. I understand Shiny's grid system may make this difficult enough to not be worth it, but if there is an elegant solution that I haven't thought of or found I would appreciate the help. I found a "[verticalLayout](https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/reference/verticalLayout.html)" function but could not get this to work or conceptualize how it functions as the documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: I've not seen a select-input rotated in any html/css interface, much less shiny. Is there an example you can point to in order to demonstrate it is possible?

Comment: I am saying that I do not know if it is possible, so sadly I cannot point to an example